# GitHub: 'master' not visible in List of branches

Tags: git, github

I am very new to Git.

- I created a new repository - `Tutorial`
- Under that I created two branches - `demo-branch` and `tutorial-branch`, one by one, and did some changed and pushed
- I checked in GitBash, that I have three branches - `master` and above two

[image]

However, when I visit GitHub online in browser, it shows me **only two branches**
[image]

[image]

Why is `master` branch not shown ? Am I conceptually missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't push `master` to GitHub, you can't see `master` branch on GitHub.

I assumed you created `Tutorial` repo from bash, not from GitHub. `master` branch is automatically created by Git on a new repository but not pushed. To get the branch on GitHub do `git push origin master:master`.

This command push onto `origin` git repository the local branch **`master`** to remote branch `master` and create it if needed.

- `origin` is the default name of remote repository. In your case this is your GitHub repository.
- Local `master` branch is your ... local master branch
- Remote branch `master` is the branch on `origin` remote, so GitHub. This one is updated when user push onto `master` branch

Comment: `git push origin master:master` means to push a local repo named `master` to a remote repo `master` ?

Comment: Btw, thanks ! I really missed this part that I have not pushed `master` to Github